# How to concatenate ENV variables with values and path in Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, axios, environment-variables

I got `env.variable` below `VUE_BASE_API=http://111.123.144.45:5331` (example), after that I export this variable as `baseAPI` and I want to concatenate with path: '/api/Users/GetUser?Name=' and value from `input-> userSearchInputValue`.

When I try to concatenate those 3 while I try to fetch data, I fail and get error below in console where between concatenating I get undefined, where it comes from?

Error

[image: 1]

```
 <input
     v-model="userSearchInputValue"
     type="text"
     name=""
     id=""
     placeholder="User"
     @keyup="searchUser(userSearchInputValue)"
/>

searchUser(userSearchInputValue) {
      axios
        .get(
          baseAPI + `/api/Users/GetUser?Name=${userSearchInputValue}`
        )
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Can someone help? Is this somehow possible?

Comment: can you add where/how `baseAPI` is defined (are you sure its defined properly-can you add a log)? if you're using string templating why not add `baseAPI` to it (`${baseAPI}/api...`)?

Comment: try this process.env.VUE_BASE_API instaead of baseAPI

Comment: if I were debugging this I would `console.log(baseAPI)` to make sure it was the correct value.  same with `userSearchInputValue`.  maybe even concatenate the whole string beforehand and console.log it to verify the entire URL is correct before using it in `axios.get()`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your replies, @depperm I define this API in apihelpers.js where I export it and after that I import it where I need it. https://imgur.com/uvrTTwc
-yoduh & -meetvaghsiya I will try your potential solutions and advises, I appreciate your effort a lot! Have a nice day!

Comment: @yoduh I tried to console.log/fetch the API again and I got now console error: "TypeError: parsed is undefined"
.When I try to fetch another API, everything works even with the same address. I tried chaning env name and without success..

Comment: @meetvaghsiya I tried that and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

As answer to this issue, I found out that you should restart your serve after declaring ENV variables - didn't knew this..